# Does the cloud version of Lightroom require an internet connection?

Tags: lightroom, lightroom-6

I’m finally resigned to the fact that I may need to start paying for Lightroom in subscription form rather than just buying it outright.

The one thing I’m still worried about is whether Lightroom CC (the cloud-based, subscription version) requires an internet connection in order to work. I know that many games use DRM systems that won’t allow an application to be launched until they can “phone home” and verify that the user’s license is good. Does Lightroom work this way? If I’m without an internet connection for some period of time will I be able to continue using Lightroom locally on my machine?

Comment: [Related](http://photo.stackexchange.com/q/57713/4141).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Adobe Creative Cloud requires an Internet connection to install the apps and to periodically verify the licensing, but not constantly. You can use the applications offline for a period of time.

https://www.adobe.com/creativecloud.html#top-questions

> 2. Do I need to be online to access my desktop apps?
>
> No, the desktop applications in Creative Cloud, such as Photoshop and
>   Illustrator, are installed directly on your computer, so you don't
>   need an ongoing Internet connection to use them. An Internet
>   connection is required the first time you install and license your
>   apps, but you can use the apps in offline mode with a valid software
>   license. The desktop apps will attempt to validate your software
>   licenses every 30 days. For annual members, you can use the apps for
>   up to 99 days in offline mode. Month-to-month members can use the
>   software for up to 30 days in offline mode.

Comment: IAW, you are SOL when the 30/99 day limit expires while you are in the field...

Comment: I've read that if you are going to be without an internet connection for an extended time, you can contact Adobe Customer Support, they have a process to allow you to access it for an extended time, probably limited to the time pre-payed for by your membership.

Answer (score 1):

While you do not need internet connection for the Adobe products to work, other than for validation every 30 days, there is a stand alone version that you can buy outright [or upgrade to from a previous version] but will not have the mobile capabilities that the cloud version has. Lightroom 6 [aka Lightroom CC with cloud disabled] works very well for me with dropbox integration. Hope that helps.