# Is Lightroom CC 2017 usable when offline?

Tags: lightroom

I was wondering if somebody know if it's possible to use the new LR CC offline?
I am hesitating to transfer my catalog to LR CC.
Thanks for your answers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the cloud version of Lightroom require an internet connection?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62021/does-the-cloud-version-of-lightroom-require-an-internet-connection)

Comment: this is not a duplicate as the new LR, which confusingly adopts the name of the old product, is an entirely new software with a tight cloud integration. it's not at all clear weather internet is only required for license verification.

Comment: Why not ask Adobe ?  They ought to know.

Comment: @StephenG Reading the page describing the Oct 2017 Adobe changes and the follow-up blog you find lots of unanswered questions.  Understandably.  http://blogs.adobe.com/lightroomjournal/2017/10/answering-your-questions-on-lightroom-cc-lightroom-classic-cc-and-more.html http://blogs.adobe.com/photoshop/2017/10/introducing-lightroom-cc-lightroom-classic-cc-and-more.html.  Hence why I too have turned to this forum.

Comment: I meant *you* asking Adobe Support your specific question, not waiting for someone else to or hoping that Adobe will say it without prompting.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested it and can confirm that it works. However the search is disabled when offline for some reason and for me that would be enough of a dealbreaker to stick to Lightroom Classic.